# how to maintain user preferences across multiple domains in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, cross-domain, expressionengine, redirectwithcookies

i am developing a multilingual site in expression engine. and i am using different domains for different languages versions of site eg: www.site.en, www.site.jp, etc.

now i want to track the visitors language preference that is i want to find out which of these domains was visited by that user/system(no user login feature) in the last.
suppose i visit www.site.com and i switch to www.site.jp and close my browser.

so next time when the user visits any of these domains i want to redirect the user to the domain(www.site.jp in this case) he visited last.

The problem is that i can't set a cookie for another domain.
Neither do i have a user login feature.
Nor do i want to user third party cookies coz it won't be reliable system.

Comment: a suggestion in core php or any other language will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right before redirect user to www.site.jp, you should set a cookie in www.site.com. Therefore, when user visit again in www.site.com the cookie is readable in your PHP script, and you can redirect again.

If user visit directly into www.site.jp, you need not to bother that, cause the site is already in Japanese.

**OR**
always redirect to www.site.com/setcookie?lang=xx,
before any domain switching and right after cookie set, do the necessary redirect

So, in theory, www.site.com always keep a cookie for the last selected language, and you can use that to redirect to www.site.xx

**OR**
instead using multiple domain name, using seconds level directory for separation, like

```
www.site.com/en
www.site.com/jp
www.site.com/zh
```

Comment: i considered your first option. but what if the user then goes from site.jp to site.fr then how will i know that language preference is site.fr when he visits site.com then next time.

Comment: and the second option is what's i'm using rite now so that's fine but i need to change the domains altogether. so any more thoughts plz share... thanks

Comment: @Avdhesh Bansal - this probably a gray area ... **what IF** the user want to select JP but your script already redirect him to FR ? I will update the answer again for your second question

Comment: although not very neat but still site.com/setcookie?lang=xx method does fit in. and if the user wants to select jp then for that i have a language override option like a dropdown  where he'll have a option to switch language from all those sites to any other.